# Installed 15.10 and now it won't boot up. I had 14.04 before - worked well

Tags: 15.10

It is pretty much the same problem, but I just want to add following:
The system asked for both login and password.
I don't remember that I ever used both login and password question before. 
The machine is an old HP530 that I got from a friend, now using double boot, Ubuntu and Windows Vista. I could not pass through the codes, but now I am thinking, could it possibly be that the system asked for the Windows codes?
After rebooting the login and password question did not come back.